# networkx から得られた隣接行列の要素だけを取り出して、csvファイルに書き込みたい

Tags: python, networkx

以下のコードを書いており、csvファイルに書き込むときに、要素のみ、かつ配列の[[, ]]を消去したいのですが、そのような方法はあるのでしょうか。

また、今回の例では３×３の行列ですが、将来的には２０×２０の行列なども考えています。

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(3, 3)
ary = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)
ary_new = np.array2string(ary, separator=', ', formatter={'int_kind': lambda x: '{: .4f}'.format(x)})

import csv

with open('python_nx_data/square.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f) 
    writer.writerows(ary)
```

以下の図のように出力したいです。
[image: 理想の結果]

上記でも書きましたが、将来的には大きな行列で行おうとしているので、printで書き出して、直接貼り付けるという解決は考えていません。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
ary = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)
```

を以下のように変えればいいと思います。

```py
ary = nx.to_numpy_array(G)
```

少数ではなく整数の0、1にしたければ`dtype`で指定できます。

```py
ary = nx.to_numpy_array(G, dtype=int)
```

以下の行は不要です（念のため）。

```py
ary_new = np.array2string(ary, separator=', ', formatter={'int_kind': lambda x: '{: .4f}'.format(x)})
```

Comment: まさに欲しかった結果です！ありがとうございます！